# Send push notifications to iOS using APNS

Tags: journeybuilder, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

Using the Journey Builder dor Android it is possible to send push notifications using the GCM, since we have the API key and registration Ids. That is much easier for testing than having to use the mobile-push platform. The iOS guide of the SDK does not say anything about a similar approach.

To send a push by APNs using a simple http post method the apple docs tell us, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html), that using this call:

HTTP POST https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/DEVICE-TOKEN

HEADERS:

apns-topic TOPIC-usually the bundle identifier

BODY: PAYLOAD

Should do the work. But this is giving me the BadDeviceToken response, I triple checked the device token and it is correct. My suspicion is that the apns-topic registered by the ETPush lib is not the bundle identifier of my app, because changing the topic to whatever value results in the same error message.

Is there a way for testing the apns push the same way as gcm push?

Comment: Could you please provide the header details, how you are referring the certificate for authentication in the header. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just found the problem, there are two environments in the mobile push platform, one for production and another for development, each one has to have its own certificate, in our case the only one that was configured was the production server, so just changing the domain to:

http://api.push.apple.com/3/device/DEVICE_TOKEN

did the trick. The apns-topic is the bundle identifier.